# Using ExpressionProperties to access different model templateOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

Firstly I would like to say Angular Formly is a fantastic library for novices such as myself. I am not a web developer, however find this library to be intuitive and powerful.

However I do need assistance with use of Expression Properties.

I have a model library which contains library items, for example:

```
{
  "itemId":"STX001",
  "title":"Grey Wolf",
  "category":"White", etc.
}
{
  "itemId":"STX002",
  "title":"Noble Black",
  "category":"Black", etc.
}
etc.
```

I also have a formly form which uses `ui-select` in top field to lookup all values from Library, select one of these (I will call this `Item`), and then populate remaining fields in the form with `Items` properties, then submit form to `Catalogue` model.

The problem I am facing is I cannot reference the properties of `Item` from within other fields. I have tried using `expressionProperties` but can only extract the `valueProp` value (which is uniqueID), however I am after Item.title, Item.category, etc.

Code below:

```
{
 //This is form fields for creating a new Catalogue entry
 key: 'libraryId',
 type: 'ui-select',
 templateOptions: {
    label: gettextCatalog.getString('Search Library'),
    options: [],
    valueProp: 'itemId',
    itemTitle: 'title',
    itemCategory: 'category',
    labelProp: 'title',
    focus: true,
    placeholder: 'Start typing keywords..'
 },
 controller: function ($scope) {
   getLibrary().then(function(data){
       $scope.options.templateOptions.options = data;
       return data;
   });
 }
}
{
 key: 'title',
 type: 'input',
 templateOptions: {
    label: gettextCatalog.getString('Name'),
    required: true
 },
 expressionProperties : {
   //This is what i'm trying to achieve but doesn't work
   'templateOptions.placeholder' : 'model.libraryId.itemTitle'
 }
},
```

Comment: Could you generate a plunkr, this will really help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the call back function provided

```
expressionPropertyObj = {
                    'templateOptions.required': (model, formState: any, field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
                        console.log('model',model);
                        console.log('state',formState);
                        console.log('field',field);
                      
                    },
```